# Using AudioWorkletProcessor for low-latency audio scheduling?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext, audio-worklet

I have an interactive music sequencing application using the following setup:

1. User makes changes in UI to manipulate audio node graph.
2. A simple WebWorker is responsible for keeping time. It sends a "tick" message to the main thread on a regular interval.
3. A listener in the main thread receives the message and performs the next step in the song (playing a sample using AudioBufferSourceNode.start, adjusting volume parameters, etc).

Having a timer in a WebWorker is more reliable than just using setInterval, but there can still be a delay before the message is processed by the main thread, leading to audio glitches.

It seems like the ideal solution would be doing step 3 in the WebWorker but [AudioContext is not supported in workers](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api-v2/issues/16). So that leaves AudioWorklet as the only low-latency web audio API. But it's a single node in the graph, while I'm looking for a way to manage the whole thing. Other than rewriting the whole system to run in the AudioWorkletProcessor (a lot of work) is there a way to use the processor for accurate scheduling, but keep the existing graph structure?

Answer (score 1):

The AudioContext has its own clock, use it.

- if you know in advance what has to be done, then you could use the first param of your [`AudioBufferSourceNode.start(delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/start) method:

```
node1.start( ctx.currentTime + 1 ); // in one second
node2.start( ctx.currentTime + 2 ); // in two seconds
node3.start( ctx.currentTime + 3 ); // in three seconds
```

- if you want to react to the end of the previous' buffersource, use its [`onended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/ended_event) event listener:

```
node.onended = (evt) => startANewNode();
```

- if you want to have a parallel timer, use a setTimeout loop that corrects itself for possible drifts:

```
const duration = 1000;
let expected = ctx.currentTime + duration;
function loop() {
  const drift = expected - ctx.currentTime;
  startANewNode();
  setTimeout( loop, duration - drift );
}
setTimeout( loop, duration );
```

And of course you could even combine all these points, together to create your own timer based entirely on the AudioContext's clock.